# Extension method not working if I set controller property in Action, works in OnExecuting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, extension-methods, html-helper

I have a class MyController that inherits from Controller, so all my controllers inherit from MyController.

I have a property in MyController:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public string SomeProperty {get;set;}
}
```

if I set this property in MyController's OnExecuting method, my HtmlHelper extension method **works fine**:

```
public static string SomeExtension(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();            
        string result = "";
    var controller = htmlHelper.ViewContext.Controller as MyController;
    if (controller != null)
    {
        result = controller.SomeProperty;
    }

       return result;
}
```

**it doesn't work if I set 'SomeProperty' in my controllers action method.**

I guess because I am doing 'as MyController' in the extension method?

*is there a way for it to work in both situations?*

I am using the value of SomeProperty to be outputted on my view pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use properties on a base controller to pass data to the view. I would recommend you writing a [custom action filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381609.aspx) and store data inside `ViewData` which will be accessible everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

How about using a common base class for all your ViewModels and then in the Html Helper, use reflection to get the values fom it?

```
Type type = htmlHelper.GetType();
PropertyInfo prop = type.GetProperty("YourPropertyName");
string value = prop.GetValue(htmlHelper.ViewData.Model, null).ToString();
```

And if you don't like the reflection part, why not just pass the property into the Html Helper?